# Inserting data in SQLite Database vs using SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

i got a little question about the performance of inserting data in sqlite (Android). I have data in the following structure:

0 | 1

0 | 2

1 | 3

...

They are in some cases very large (about 50,000 lines). I wanted to manage the data with SQLite, but somehow the inserting process takes very long (nearly 1 minute)! If i save them in SharedPreferences, it nearly happens instantly.

My inserting code looks like this:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    long id;
    db.beginTransaction();
    try{
        values.put(KEY_FRIENDIDONE,firstFriendID);
        values.put(KEY_FRIENDIDTWO,secondFriendID);
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT,getDateTime());

        System.out.println(firstFriendID+" "+secondFriendID);

        id= db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_FRIENDSHIPS,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    return id;
```

So i am asking myself if i should user SharedPreferences instead of SQLite.

Btw the IDs are saved as Integer. However i don't now if that makes a difference if i save them as Strings.

Comment: Have you tried inserting 50000 elements in 1 transaction, instead of in 50000 transactions?

Comment: @Sully SharedPreferences are not for large data set like your requirement. SQLite query are little bit annoying but we have lots of third party libraries to manage Sqlite. Ormlite is one the best and easy to understand for newbie.

Comment: I would like to know, why this is like that. I searched for an example tutorial concerning sqlite in android and they also looped over multiple transactions. So it is always better to insert a set of data than giving the opportunity to loop over one funtion to add one row of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should insert your `50.000` rows in a transaction like:

```
db.beginTransaction();
for(i = 0 -> i = 50.000) doInsert();
// end trasaction here.
```

you should take a look at [GreenDao](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO), it helps you improve a lot with db management and performance with some kind of code like:

```
friendsDao.insertTx(new Friends(id1,id2,time));
```